# Electrical wiring problem in panel when using 220 volt log splitter

Tags: electrical-panel

I have had this electrical panel for 15 years with no problems.  I have six 110v circuits and one 220v circuit.  One of my 110v circuits to several outlets suddenly went dead but did not trip the circuit breaker.  Now, when I plug in my log splitter into my 220v circuit it just hums,  but the dead 110v circuit comes alive.

Could this be caused by bad circuit breakers on either my 220v or 110v circuit?  Please advise.

Comment: It sounds like you lost a leg and the log splitter being on 240 is making the connection to that outlet. The one outlet that is dead is that the only one I would guess all odd or even breakers would be dead in that panel and none of the 240 stuff will work correctly.

Comment: No, it's not breakers, it's your service.

Comment: Is this panel a main panel or a subpanel?

Comment: @Harper -- if it's a subpanel, then the *feeder* could be the culprit...

Comment: 2 of 3 110 ckts on right side are out;  and 3 110 ckts on left are ok but 220 on left is out.  this is a subpanel but it does not come off the main panel so there is no breaker to the sub panel.

Answer (score 1):

With multiple dead outlets on each side you have lost a leg as I said so there will not be power on the odd or even breakers under load with no load there may still be a conductive path creating some voltage at an outlet but no ability to support a load. When you turn on a 240 device the power is being delivered to the the bad leg through this device or log splitter. All the odd breakers are connected to 1 leg and all the even are connected to the other leg for single pole. The supply to the panel from the main has a problem. It could be the breaker in the service panel that feeds the sub or 1 wire connecting the breaker to the panel or someplace in between so all the breakers on the odd or even side (L1 or L2 will be dead). Check at the service panel for 120 to neutral on each then 240 across the 2 then check the sub the same way. If you see 240 at the service connection but not at the sub and the connections look good the feeder wire has a break someplace in between.